# оптимизация cURL запроса

Tags: php, curl

Пытаюсь спарсить данные с сайта, ну очень большое время на выполнения. Если парсить данные с одной страницы то время выполнения более нормально. При попытки парсинга 100 страниц сразу, выполняется n-е количество времени. Может кто подскажет как можно оптимизировать. Долго выполняется блок while. Я конечно понимаю что не быстро все, ну может что то порекомендуете.

```
$url = 'http://elibr.com.ua/cat';

    function go($url, $q = null){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');

        if($q != null){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$q);

        }   
        $out = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $out;
    }

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ //когда отправляю кнопку парсить
        $start = microtime(true);
        $country = $_POST['countryid']; //1-й параметр 
        $count   = $_POST['count']; // всего записей заранее известно
        $count =  ceil($count / 100); //2-й параметр, для определения номера страницы. На одной странице отображается 100 записей. 
        $array = array(); //сюда сохраняется данные

        $i = 1;

//поочередно парсим каждую страницу
        while($i <= $count){

            if ($i == 1){
                $q = "countryid=".$country."&order=0&sortorder=0&titleboxid=0"; //строка для 1-го запроса
            }else{
                $q = "countryid=".$country."&order=0&sortorder=0&titleboxid=0&pagenum=".$i; //строка для n-го запроса, меняем страницу
            }

            $html = go($url, $q);
            //$array[] = parseTable($html); //вырезается нужные данные.
            $i++;

        }


        $time = microtime(true) - $start;
        printf('Скрипт выполнялся %.4F сек.', $time);

    }
```

PS: сильно за код не критикуйте :)

Comment: На http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php не смотрели?

Comment: Я запускаю парсер всегда из CLI окружения. Но если вам надо из браузера - предлагаю вам тогда слать аякс запрос - парсить и после каждой страницы аозвращать результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Не стоит каждый раз создавать и уничтожать хэндлер curl. Один раз создали через `curl_init()`, и гоняйте его со всеми запросами.
2. Может чуть ускорить дело распараллеливание запросов через [`curl_multi_..`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php), но не слишком: сервер на той стороне тоже, может, не монстр. Я бы попробовал сравнить скорость в один поток и в 4. Т.е. сразу запрашиваете 4 страницы, а не одну.

Примерно так, не проверял:

```
$url = 'http://elibrary.ru/titles.asp';
$nThreads = 4;  // сколько потоков
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$ch = array();
for( $thread=0; $thread<$nThreads; $thread++) {
    array_push( $ch, curl_init());
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch[ $thread],
        array(
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6',
            CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 5,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => '',
            CURLOPT_POST            => true,
            CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
            CURLOPT_REFERER         => $url,
        )
    );
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ //когда отправляю кнопку парсить
    $start = microtime(true);
    $country = $_POST['countryid']; //1-й параметр 
    $count   = $_POST['count']; // всего записей заранее известно
    $count =  ceil($count / 100); //2-й параметр, для определения номера страницы. На одной странице отображается 100 записей. 
    $array = array(); //сюда сохраняется данные

    $i = 1;

    $postData = array(
        "countryid"     => $country,
        "order"         => 0,
        "sortorder"     => 0,
        "titleboxid"    => 0,
        "pagenum"       => 0,
    );

    // парсим пачками по $nThreads страниц
    while($i <= $count){
        for( $thread=0; $thread<$nThreads; $thread++) {
            if( $i > $count) {  // последняя пачка не полностью
                $removed = array_splice( $ch, $thread); // удалить лишние 
                for( $j=0; $j<count($removed); $j++) curl_close( $removed[$j]);
                break;
            }

            $postData['pagenum'] = $i;
            curl_setopt( $ch[ $thread], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
            $i++;
        }

        // пачка готова
        for( $thread=0; $thread<count($ch); $thread++) curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch[ $thread]);

        $active = null;
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

        while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
            if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
                do {
                    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
                } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
            }
        }

        for( $thread=0; $thread<count($ch); $thread++) {
            $html = curl_multi_getcontent( $ch[ $thread]);
            // $array[] = parseTable($html);                //вырезается нужные данные.
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[ $thread]);
        }
    }


    $time = microtime(true) - $start;
    printf('Скрипт выполнялся %.4F сек.', $time);

}
```